# Is there a more compact way to write this ROR code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a more compact way to write the following code.  I would like to get rid of the line that assigns the empty string when flash[:add_run_error] is nil.

```
unless run.save 
  run.errors.each do |attr, msg|  
    flash[:add_run_error] += '<br/>' if flash[:add_run_error] 
    flash[:add_run_error] = '' unless flash[:add_run_error] 
    flash[:add_run_error] += "Invalid #{attr}.  Follow examples below." 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Also, try to avoid using the + method on strings. Each time a string is "plussed" in Ruby, it generates a new object. Use << instead. Or do as jdl said. =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply join the `attr` part of your errors together.

```
flash[:add_run_error] = run.errors.map{|attr, msg| "Invalid #{attr}.  Follow examples below."}.join('<br/>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
unless run.save 
  add_run_errors = []
  run.errors.each do |attr, msg|  
    add_run_errors << "Invalid #{attr}.  Follow examples below." 
  end 
  flash[:add_run_error] = add_run_errors.join '<br />'
end
```

But it is without first `<br />` - you can add it simply:

```
  flash[:add_run_error] = '<br /'> + (add_run_errors.join '<br />')
```